# How to get a div to scroll right to left jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'd like to have images (and/or a single wide image) move slowly from right to left in a sort of slide show and then pause on mouseover. I also want to have left and right arrows which will change the direction of the slideshow on click. I'm not sure what this is called or how to do it.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling this question will not go over too well with the community

Comment: I just wanna know what it's called so I can find the plug in / code.

Comment: google "jquery gallery rotator"

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollLeft to scroll left or right 
Not much related to the current question but certainly help other users..

```
       $(document).ready(function () {

     // Creating two Left Right Scroll Button through JQuery
        var  btnRht= $("<input type='button' id='btnLeft' value='>>' class='ButtonStyle' width='5px' />");
     var  btnLeft = $("<input type='button' id='btnRight' value='<<' class='ButtonStyle' />");
           // appending buttons to a td inside a html div 
        $('#tdDoE').append(btnLeft);
    $('#tdDoE').append(btnRht);
    // Left / Rht Scroll scroll     
                $("#btnLeft").click(function () { 
                var leftPos = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
                $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 250}, 600);
                });   
                    $("#btnRight").click(function () { 

                var leftPos2 = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
                $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos2 - 250}, 600);
                });   

    });
```

HTML Code :-

```
       <div style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;" class="DivDataMain">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="tdDoE">
                        Scroll Buttons will be appended after this text.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```